# Actionscript 3: Run function when mouse down is pressed, everyewhere else than on a listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an event listener for CLICK on a movie clip. It is very difficult to make a transparent listener behind the movie clip, because of how the stage is arranged. Is there a way I can run a function when you click anywhere else but the listener?

```
    fash.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fashRun);
```

Comment: Subscribe to stage for **MouseEvent.CLICK** so you will get all the clicks and check if mouse inside or outside any area you want with **DisplayObject.hitTestPoint(...)** as a condition: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint()

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this

Comment: Whatever is in front (blocking) of the target can be made invisible to mouse with commands like `blocker.mouseChildren = false;` and `blocker.mouseEnabled = false;`... try using both for same blocker.

Answer (score 0):

See [this API](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint())

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
   if (!fash.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true))
   {
     //todo
   }
}
```